# fullcalendar: is there a way to call dayRender only after i load my events via events function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

i'm using fullcalendar in a web application i"m building.

i load my events with [events function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/) and ajax.

here is my code:

```
var ajaxData;
var eventsJsonArray;
var json_backgrundColor;
var json_iconstring;

//alert('Hello! 1!');
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        //custom events function to be called every time the view changes
        events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
            var mStart = start.format('M')
            var yStart = start.format('YYYY')
            $.ajax({
                url: '$getMonthDataUrl',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    startDate: start.format(),
                    endDate: end.format()
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('nice!!');
                    ajaxData = data;
                    json_iconstring = ajaxData['iconString'];
                    json_backgrundColor = ajaxData['Calendar_cell_background_color'];
                    eventsJsonArray = ajaxData['all_Events_For_The_Month'];
                    callback(eventsJsonArray); //pass the event data to fullCalendar via the supplied callback function
                }
            });
        },
        fixedWeekCount: false,
        showNonCurrentDates: false,

        dayRender: function (date, cell, view) {
            console.log(json_backgrundColor);//this brings eror because json_backgrundColor is undefined 
            var cellDate = date.format('D');
            if (date.format('M') == view.start.format('M')) //cheacking is this day is part of the currrent month (and not prev/next month)
            {
                alert(cellDate);
                cell.css('background-color', json_backgrundColor[cellDate]);//this brings eror because json_backgrundColor is undefined 

            }


        },
    })

});
```

when i load my events via ajax i'm also getting the information about which background color each cell should get. i can only get this info via the events ajax request.

the problem is that when the dayRender is running, i still don't have the background color data. (json_backgrundColor is undefined).

is there a way that dayRender will run after the events calendar will stop running? or any other code that will fix my problem.

many thanks!!

Comment: i don't mind that the default color will be white until the events are rendered, but after they render i want the color to change immediately.

Comment: I  don't know if that is an answer, I'm not familiar with the API, just thought it might be something simple like that. `cell.css('background-color', json_backgrundColor && json_backgrundColor[cellDate] || 'white');` just checks if there is a value in the variable before access and supplies a default if not.

Comment: I think it's potentially a semantic error to combine the download of event data with data which relates to whole days in the same ajax call. Can you explain what the purpose is of the custom background colours, and how they are calculated? Is it predictable, static information such as public holidays? Or is the colour used related in some way to the events that are scheduled that day? (e.g. maybe it changes colour if there are too many events, or certain types of events? I don't know, just trying to understand the reasons for it).

Comment: the colours change according to the events rendered in the specific day. it's all determinate in the backend. i don't think that i can change this one. is there any solution with fullcalendar?

Comment: ok I see. So it's tied directly to the nature of the events for that specific day. I think there is a way. Will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the "dayRender" callback runs after the view is changed (changing the date using prev/next counts as changing the view, for this purpose), but before the events for the new view have been downloaded and rendered. That's why your `json_backgrundColor` array is undefined.

Since you mentioned that the colour to be used depends on the exact nature of the events currently scheduled for that specific day, we need to find something that we can run after all the events, and this colour data, have been downloaded.

Inspecting the HTML, we can see that the table cells used to draw each day all have the CSS class "fc-day" applied. They also have a `data-date` property containing the day that they relate to. Finally, days that are disabled (outside the main month, due to you setting `showNonCurrentDates:false`) have an extra class of "fc-disabled-day" applied. We can use these pieces of information to identify the cells we want to change, without having to use the `dayRender` callback.

The `eventAfterAllRender` callback runs once when all the events have been rendered. Therefore this seems like a good place to alter the background colours of the cells:

```
eventAfterAllRender(function(view) {
    //loop through each non-disabled day cell
    $('.fc-day:not(.fc-disabled-day)').each(function(index, element) {
      //set the background colour of the cell from the json_backgroundColor arrray, based on the day number taken from the cell's "data-date" attribute.
      $(this).css('background-color', json_backgroundColor[moment($(this).data("date")).format("D")]);
    });
}
```

Note that I have renamed `json_backgrundColor` to `json_backgroundColor` to correct the spelling error.

N.B. This is brittle in the sense that it relies on the class names that fullCalendar uses internally to represent the day cells. If fullCalendar decides to do this differently in a future release, it will break (whereas if we were able to use the fullCalendar API via the designated callbacks, they would likely maintain consistency despite internal changes, or at least document any change). But it's pretty key to the Month view, so realistically it's not likely to change any time soon - you would just have to remember to test it if you update your fullCalendar version.

Comment: well. once again thank u. it works. i have now 2 different issues that it will really help me if u could help:
1. i want to post an icon according to an array. "$(this).css.prepend('<img src=\' $assetsPath/fullcalendar/icons/havdala2.png \'>');" this line does not work inside the scope of  $('.fc-day:not(.fc-disabled-date)').each(function(index, element) {}
2. can u please right the code given that i *don't* use showNonCurrentDates:false, because i dont think i will use this setting in the end

Comment: `$(this).css.prepend` makes no sense - you can't attach _HTML markup_ to the _CSS properties_ of the element. `$(this).prepend` ought to work though.

Comment: in regards to your other question - I wrote the answer based on your given code. It works in that scenario - in that case please accept the answer, thanks :-). Changing the requirements after you ask, and have the question answered correctly, is not really fair on those answering and the effort they have made.

Comment: FWIW I don't think there's any easy way to do this without using `showNonCurrentDates:false`, because your `json_backgroundColor` array doesn't include info about which month each entry refers to. If you change it to an object where the keys are full dates (in yyyy-mm-dd format), you could do it. Also it would need to return data for all days between `start` and `end`, not just the main month, otherwise those extra days would not get the correct colour applied.

Comment: you are right regarding changing the question . anyway, now i have a different issue, not sure why. it seems that the background color of the NonCurrentDates are changing to the background color cell of json_backgroundColor ['24']. this is based on the code u posted.

Comment: sorry, there was a typo - should be `:not(.fc-disabled-day)` instead of `:not(.fc-disabled-date)` Have updated the answer. If that is working please remember to mark as the accepted answer - thanks :-)

Comment: ok now it works fine! last question i guess: how can i target the nonCurrentDates cell's? i would like to change their background color to white. right now it's grey.

Comment: `$('.fc-disabled-day').css(...`. Is that not obvious? We used "not" to exclude them based on the selector, so if you want to find them, the same selector can be used...

Answer (score 1):

if anyone still wondering you can use dateSet option like

```
datesSet: event => {
                var from = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                var to = moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                dateStatus = getEachDateStatus(from, to);
               //{'2022-11-10' : 'fullbooked', '2022-11-09' : 'halfBooked'};
                Object.keys(dateStatus).forEach(key => {
                    $('td[data-date="'+key+'"]').addClass(dateStatus[key]);
                });
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on `dayRender`, you should create background color events based on your ajax:

```js
events = [
...
{ date: date
 color: ...
 rendering: 'background'
 className: 'my-class'
}]
```

You can transform events using css any way you like, with or without the `rendering: 'background'` option.